# Como guardar as variáveis para serem usadas nos próximos .Java?

Tags: android, xml, web-service, parser

Meu código principal (do parser) está desta maneira:

```
public class pFormasDePagamento {

public static void parseXML(String xml)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    String valFormaOutros = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(0)
            .getTextContent();
    String descForma = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(0)
            .getTextContent();
    String valForma = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(1)
            .getTextContent();
    String descForma1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(1)
            .getTextContent();
    String valForma1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(2)
            .getTextContent();
    String descForma2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(2)
            .getTextContent();
    String valForma2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(3)
            .getTextContent();
    String descForma3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(3)
            .getTextContent();
    String valForma3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(4)
            .getTextContent();
    String descForma4 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(4)
            .getTextContent();
    String valForma4 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(5)
            .getTextContent();
    String descForma5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(5)
            .getTextContent();
    String valForma5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(6)
            .getTextContent();
}}
```

Gostaria de guardar todas essas strings (valForma1...5) para serem reutilizadas em outros .Java

Como eu posso resolver isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma classe que contenha essas propriedades e retorne uma instancias(em um array, por exemplo) dessa classe.

Tipo assim:

```
public class FormaDePagamento {
    public String desc;
    public String valor;
}

public class pFormasDePagamento {

    public static FormaDePagamento[] parseXML(String xml)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        FormaDePagamento[] formas = new FormaDePagamento[5];
        for(int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
            formas[n] = new FormaDePagamento();
            formas[n].desc = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(n).getTextContent();
            formas[n].valor = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(n).getTextContent();
        }

        return formas;
    }
}
```

/* em:  "formas[n].val = doc.getElementsByTagName" não seria: "formas[n].valor = doc.getElementsByTagName"  ?
*/

Comment: como eu iria fazer a chamada então Rafael?

Comment: como eu posso chamar as variáveis separadas @RafaelTelles?

Comment: Poderia ser algo como "FormaDePagamento[] formas = pFormasDePagamento.parseXML(xml)", e nessa array você teria todos os objetos do xml.

Answer (score 0):

Renan, você pode usar o banco de dados nativo do Android Sqlite ou SharedPreferences.
No caso do SharedPreferences é bem simples, e pode ser utilizado na sua Activity dessa maneira:

```
public static final String KEY = "nome_chave";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
/*Para armazenar um valor*/
sharedPreferences.edit().putString(KEY , "valor").commit();
/*Para ler um valor armazenado*/
sharedPreferences.getString(KEY , "valor padrão caso não tenha valor para a chave");
```